# JSP Error: the requested resource is not available

Tags: java, html

I am new in this site and as a programmer I consider myself to be beginner/intermediate level. I am new in java and have to work with JSP for an University course. I want to know what is wrong with this code because I am receiving this error:

> the requested resource is not available.

Here is all my code:

session.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<form method = Post action = “receiveName.jsp”>
please enter your name: <input type = "text" name = "myname" size = 20></br>
<input type = "submit"><input type = "clear">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

receiveName.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="mynames.Names" scope="session"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="myNames" param="myname"/>

<% String name = bean.getMyNames();
session.setAttribute(“user”, name);
%>
<html>
<body>
<a href = “showname.jsp”>move to next page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

showName.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
Hello <% = session.getAttribute(“user”)%>
</body>
</html>
```

Names.java

```
package mynames;

public class Names{

    private String myNames;

    public Names(){
    }

    public void setMyNames(String name){
        myNames = name;
    }

    public String getMyNames(){
        return myNames;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to implement the concept of bean very well and if I run the receiveName.jsp alone the following report appears:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /EjemploProfesor/Class/receiveName.jsp (line: 1, column: 1) The value for the useBean class attribute mynames.Names is invalid.
```

Every input from you will be very appreciated. By the way, I am not using an IDE, just Sublime Text 2 running in Ubuntu and as server Apache Tomcat 8.0.21

Comment: Can someone help me out? If you see another simpler way to implement the bean feel free to share it. I will like to see an example with username and a password. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the `“` to `"` in your whole code.

For eg:

```
<form method = Post action = “receiveName.jsp”>
```

has to be changed to

```
<form method = Post action = "receiveName.jsp">
```

Similarly, change the below given lines

```
session.setAttribute(“user”, name);
<a href = “showname.jsp”>
Hello <% = session.getAttribute(“user”)%>
```

to

```
session.setAttribute("user", name);
<a href = "showname.jsp">
Hello <% = session.getAttribute("user")%>
```

respectively

Comment: Thanks! I did it but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the class `Names` in your receiveName.jsp

```
<%@page import="mynames.Names"%>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that but still the same result.

Comment: Could you please post your full receiveName.jsp code

Comment: That is all the code I have. Maybe it is incomplete because I'm new in JSP.